# How to click on Angular element via selenium webdriver?

Tags: angularjs, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver, webdriverwait

Need one more help on below to click() on Ask me later button.

```
<div align="center" class="mar-b0">
  <button class="custom-green md-button md-ink-ripple no-margin md-button"
          type="button" ng-transclude="" ng-click="vm.goHome();">
     <span class="ng-binding ng-scope">Ask me later</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

I have tried with below code -

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(
     By.xpath("//span[@class='ng-binding ng-scope' and contains(.,
              'ASK ME LATER')]"))).click();
```

Comment: Below is the code- <div align="center" class="mar-b0">
   <button class="custom-green md-button md-ink-ripple no-margin md-button" type="button" ng-transclude="" ng-click="vm.goHome();"><span class="ng-binding ng-scope">Ask me later</span></button>
  </div>

Comment: what happens when your code executes does it click or throws any exception?

Answer (score 0):

The element is [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so to `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element to be clickable` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.custom-green.md-button.md-ink-ripple.no-margin.md-button[ng-click*='goHome']>span.ng-binding.ng-scope"))).click();
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='custom-green md-button md-ink-ripple no-margin md-button' and contains(@ng-click, 'goHome')]/span[@class='ng-binding ng-scope' and text()='Ask me later']"))).click();
  ```

Comment: Thankyou for your support. Above code works but only works for one time. Do i need to initialize it or please suggest how to proceed.

Comment: @ShipraSaxena This solution is specific to the `<button>` element for which you have provided the HTML.